# Undefined variable 'YouTube' python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-re

I am trying to download youtube playlists with code I've found online, but I get an error that is bothering me. (I don't know anything about Python.)

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
website = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCReyWKrw9wdoyb6Z9aVhPS5r3ZTA33Ky'
r= requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
 
tgt_list = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
tgt_list = [n for n in tgt_list if re.search('watch',n)]
 
unique_list= []
for n in tgt_list:
    if n not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(n)
 
# all the videos link in a playlist
unique_list = ['https://www.youtube.com' + n for n in unique_list]
 
for link in unique_list:
    print(link)
    y = YouTube(link)
    t = y.streams.all()
    t[0].download(output_path=r"C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\New folder (2)")
```

Error:

```
 {
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Catalin/Desktop/Test/Test.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "undefined-variable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined variable 'YouTube'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 22,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 22,
    "endColumn": 9
}
```

How should I declare that variable, or what do I have to do specifically?

Comment: What is `YouTube`? A library, class etc?

Comment: Indeed, it _is_ an undefined variable. Why do you think it _should_ be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are attempting to use the `YouTube` type from `pytube` (or possibly some other package).  You'll need to:

- ensure this package is installed in your virtual environment (or global `site-packages` if you are not using a virtual environment)

  ```
  pip install pytube
  ```
- import it ...

  ```
  from pytube import YouTube
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `YouTube(link)`, but this function does not appear anywhere in your code.